# Fbprophet / pystan

Tags: python, pystan

I am tying to install Fbprophet (python)

I followed all installation instructions (anaconda).

If I try to run Fbprophet in my anaconda prompt it works fine.

However, when I create a project in Visual studio 2017 I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dommarch\source\repos\FbProphet\FbProphet\FbProphet.py", line 1, in 
    import fbprophet
  File "C:\Users\dommarch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\fbprophet__init__.py", line 8, in 
    from fbprophet.forecaster import Prophet
  File "C:\Users\dommarch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 17, in 
    import pystan  # noqa F401
  File "C:\Users\dommarch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pystan__init__.py", line 9, in 
    from pystan.api import stanc, stan
  File "C:\Users\dommarch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pystan\api.py", line 13, in 
    import pystan._api  # stanc wrapper
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

If anyone has an idea it would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: so i don't know vs 2017, but it looks like you have pystan in 2 places? envs... and app-data/roaming ...

Comment: fails the same way in pycharm too

Answer (score 0):

The version of (fb)prophet, pystan and python are important.

I managed to get it working for this stack:

```
CentOS: 7
Python: 3.8
GCC: 4.8.5
PyStan: 2.19.1.1
FbProphet: 0.7.1
```

And for this particular stack, you need GCC++ 2014 compiler, provided by this package:

```
centos-release-scl devtoolset-8
```

For **Windows**, using conda, python 3.8, steps are documented in this [article](https://medium.com/data-folks-indonesia/installing-fbprophet-prophet-for-time-series-forecasting-in-jupyter-notebook-7de6db09f93e) and will summarize below:

- Access anaconda using conda command in your command line
- Build new virtual environment e.g. time_series, this environment will run in Python 3.8,

  ```
  conda create -n time_series python=3.8
  ```
- Access your environment using this command:

  ```
  conda activate time_series
  ```
- Install the C++ compiler:

  ```
  conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
  ```
- Installation of the dependencies of fbprophet:

  conda install numpy cython -c conda-forge

  conda install matplotlib scipy pandas -c conda-forge

  conda install pystan -c conda-forge

  conda install -c anaconda ephem
- Install the library that will used for your time series forecasting environment:

  pip install scikit-learn

  pip install --user pmdarima

  conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet

Note: Fbprophet was renamed to Prophet
https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1874

So, you may need to install prophet too:

```
   pip install pystan==2.19.1.1 prophet
```

or

```
   conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

Answer (score 0):

[The package name is now **prophet** instead of **fbprophet**](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#installation-in-python)...
so for latest python versions:

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

In particular, as we see with mamba here is what is available for **fbprophet**:

```
└─ fbprophet   is installable with the potential options
   ├─ fbprophet [0.1.1|0.1.post1|...|0.5] would require
   │  └─ python [2.7* |>=2.7,<2.8.0a0 ], which can be installed;
   ├─ fbprophet [0.1.1|0.1.post1|0.2|0.2.1|0.3.post2] would require
   │  └─ python [3.5* |>=3.5,<3.6.0a0 ], which can be installed;
   ├─ fbprophet [0.1.1|0.1.post1|0.2|0.2.1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.6* , which can be installed;
   ├─ fbprophet [0.3.post2|0.4.post2|0.5|0.6|0.7.1] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
   ├─ fbprophet [0.5|0.6|0.7.1] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
   └─ fbprophet 0.7.1 would require
      └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed.
```

In more detail, for linux, but assume similar for win, **fbprophet** is available in conda-forge for older python versions:

```
Name      Version   Build          Channel             
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 fbprophet 0.7.1     py38h950e882_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.7.1     py37h3340039_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.7.1     py36h831f99a_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.6       py37he1b5a44_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.6       py36he1b5a44_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.5       py27he1b5a44_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.5       py27he1b5a44_1 conda-forge/linux-64
(... similar results of in between versions ...)
 fbprophet 0.1.1     np112py27_0    conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.1.1     np111py36_0    conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.1.1     np111py35_0    conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.1.post1 py36_0         conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.1.post1 py35_0         conda-forge/linux-64
 fbprophet 0.1.post1 py27_0         conda-forge/linux-64
```

while the same query for **prophet** returns:

```
Name    Version Build           Channel             
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 prophet 1.1.5   py310h56eac3b_1 conda-forge         
 prophet 1.1.5   py310h56eac3b_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py310h56eac3b_1 conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py311h1fff0e1_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py39h5ee1178_1  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py39h5ee1178_0  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py38h214270d_1  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py38h214270d_0  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py312h4f541b2_1 conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.5   py311h1fff0e1_1 conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.4   py38h214270d_0  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.4   py310h56eac3b_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.4   py311h1fff0e1_0 conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.4   py39h5ee1178_0  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1.4   py39h3c18c91_0  pkgs/main/linux-64  
(... similar results of in between versions ...)
 prophet 1.1     py39hf3d152e_1  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.1     py39hf3d152e_2  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py37h06a4308_0  pkgs/main/linux-64  
 prophet 1.0.1   py38h06a4308_0  pkgs/main/linux-64  
 prophet 1.0.1   py39h06a4308_0  pkgs/main/linux-64  
 prophet 1.0.1   py37h89c1867_1  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py37h085eea5_3  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py36hcb3619a_3  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py36h5fab9bb_5  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py36h5fab9bb_4  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py36h5fab9bb_2  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py36h5fab9bb_1  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py37h89c1867_2  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py37h89c1867_4  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py37h89c1867_5  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py38h578d9bd_1  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py38h578d9bd_2  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py38h578d9bd_4  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py38h578d9bd_5  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py38ha770c72_1  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py38hd0cf306_3  conda-forge/linux-64
 prophet 1.0.1   py39hf3d152e_5  conda-forge/linux-64
```